# What is <LINK rel="alternate" type="text/html" href=""> doing?

Tags: html

I am working in a project [fastfly](http://fasterfly.com/) where I found above tag.
I did a little research but couldn't get clear answer.
Any body can describe what exactly this does?

Comment: I think the questin should be about coding not about explaining

Answer (score 8):

Link `rel=alternate` tells the user (search engines) that there is an other URL with the same content but in an other form (eg. language, mobile, ...).

Source : [MDN Link types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types)

Answer (score 3):

Meaning of each part according to w3c:

**rel**: Set of space-separated tokens. Specifies a list of tokens that specify the relationship between the document containing the link and the destination indicated by the link. Two categories of links can be created using the link element -- Links to external resources and hyperlinks.

**alternate**: A type of hyperlink that gives alternate representations of the current document.

**type**: A valid MIME type that destination of the hyperlink. Gives the MIME type of the linked resource.

So basically the tag gives a reference to an alternate location of your document that might be in another language. In your case, what the link is doing, is that it is showing the same site with slight modifications, probably meant for people of a different geographical location (I'm not sure about this, but yes, it's the modified version of the same site.)

PS: Avoid posting links of websites in your questions, try posting code or a fiddle instead. The problem is that most websites undergo change over time, so the question becomes redundant for future reference.